# Unable to revert downvote on edited question

Tags: support, voting, down-votes

The following [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/146303/11069) was initially a hint, then an edit was made which was not mathematically correct. At that point I downvoted, and left a comment.

The answer has been then reedited with incorrect statements removed, and I would like to retract my down-vote, but it appear locked.

Can I edit the question to unlock it or, otherwise, what is the preferred way to work around the problem?

Comment: Hmm, you should have been able to undo your vote. I've edited the answer again, maybe see if it works now?

Comment: @ZevChonoles Thanks! I was able to retract my downvote after your edit.

Answer (score 3):

From the comments: Zev re-editted the post, and the user was able to revert the downvote. Disaster averted. `:-)`